# Possible data race condition using openMP, corrupted data

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have some code which works fine when running on one thread.  I have been using open Mp to parralellize this code. The problem is that when I use more than 1 thread I start to get corrupted results.  My best guess is that I have a data race condition somewhere in my code but I cannot find it.  Any thoughts or advice is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
omp_set_num_threads( 12 );
double average = 0;
    int x;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:average)
    for(x = 0; x<K_FOLDS_FOLDS; x++) //NEED TO PARALELLIZE THIS LOOP
    {
        double result = logistic_regression_test(xtraining[x], xtest[x], ytraining[x], ytest[x]);
        average += result;  
    }
```

The code works fine when i comment out the omp_set_num_threads.  K_FOLDS_FOLDS = 15 and the logistic_Regression_test function does a bunch of stuff and then returns a double.  Is it possible the problem is somewhere within that function?  Does a function create local variables at the same memory location every time, even if multiple threads are executing that function? This would explain the corrupted data if each function called in parallel was changing the same memory addresses.

Comment: You've misspelled `parallel`.  I would fix that first.

Comment: Local variables are local to each function invocation, otherwise recursion wouldn't work either. But yes the problem is in logistic_regression_test (assuming it isn't just the misspelled parallel). Look for any writes to global or otherwise shared variables.